# Do I need to do authentication during the message transfer

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I need to use activemq to communicate between micro-service and the system has access control to limit the user action. I already check the user from restful endpoint by spring security. After authentication, I send message to queue. Do I need to verify the user again? If yes, how can I pass the user credential by activemq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is microservices architecture already. And as what you said you have an authentication/Authorization micro-service then there is no point duplicating the checks all over again.

The best approach is to let the Gateway-Service do the authentication/authorization thing.

Usually it is bound to the Zuul implementing service. So that all calls to specific service URL got intercepted by that gateway and apply whatever security policies you have

Comment: I agree with this. However, our lead want to add authentication to identify the user when consume the message. Is it possible to use spring security with activemq?

Comment: You can do nearly anything in programming, it is always about the cost (both money and effort) and time. The following link will show you how to enable authentication over ActiveMQ and plug it in through XML config (Spring)

https://mariuszprzydatek.com/2014/01/04/token-based-authentication-plugin-for-activemq/

Comment: if this answer satisfies your requirements, do not forget to up vote it